# java multi-level scroll-able pop-up menus

Tags: java, swing, scroll, menu, jpopupmenu

I have this requirement where I need to show menus which can go multiple levels down. Now at each level there can be many objects in the menu which means I have to show a scroll bar in the menu.

```
1
 1->1
 1->2
2
```

I am able to write a custom class 'JScrollPopupMenu' which introduces a scroll bar to the menu. Now I can only control the first pop-up menu but for the next level menus I have no control over the pop-up menu being created
Example:

```
//this is the first pop-up menu
JPopupMenu scrollablePopupMenu = new JScrollPopupMenu();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("1");
scrollablePopupMenu.add(menu);
menu = new JMenu("2");
scrollablePopupMenu.add(menu);
//this is the child menu for "1", I have no control over   //childMenu.getPopupMenu(), this is created internally inside JMenu
JMenu childMenu = new JMenu("1->1");
menu.add(childMenu);
childMenu = new JMenu("1->2");
menu.add(childMenu);
```

In the above example, the first level pop-up has a scroll bar but the next level pop-up does not. Is there any way how this can be achieved?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have that many menu items you should reconsider your GUI design.

1) A thumb-rule in usability says that you should not display more than 8 selections in a group.

2) Just because Windows have a scrollable menu in the Start-menu, doesn't make it a good example. In fact, Microsoft has left that in favour of searching instead, just be because a huge scrollable menu isn't user-friendly.